# Контекст в ноде при исполнении файла

Tags: javascript, node.js

Здравствуйте, есть вопрос, имеется такой код.

```js
var obj = {
 num: 10,
 method: function(){
  function test(){
   console.log(this.num);
  } 
  test();
 }
}

obj.method(); // undefined
```

Он вернёт undefinded т.к контекст вызова функции test глобален.
Но если мы в начале объявим переменную num и присвоем ей значение.
То будет выведен результат глобального контекста.

```js
var num = 11;
var obj = {
    num: 10,
    method: function(){
        function test(){
            console.log(this.num);
        }  
        test()
    }
}

obj.method(); //11
```

Проверял в ноде и браузере и оно работает. Но в ноде работает только в режиме REPL, а если я скармливаю ему скрипт из файла то возвращает результат undefined, можете пожалуйста подсказать почему так происходит?

Comment: this в данном случае - это глобал, когда загружаешь из файла он считается модулем, num объявляется внутри модуля и this.num - _undefined_ потому что переменная объявлена в  модуле а не в глобале. В репле это работает так как верхний уровень не модуль а глобал и переменная num объявляется непосредственно в нем и доступна через this.num

Comment: @Grundy это должно было быть ответом

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ага, вчера по-быстрому написал :-) надо подумать как оформить лучше, это кстати не дубликат того вопроса про потерю контекста?

Comment: @Grundy точно нет. Тут ведь автор понимает механизм потери контекста, но не понимал механизм модулей в ноде.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, добавил ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отличие nodejs от браузера в том, что она уже поддерживает модули в javascript.

Важное отличие модулей заключается в том, что переменные объявленные с помощью `var` глобально для модуля - добавляются не в глобальный объект, а в модуль.

Любой файл расценивается как модуль, поэтому при использовании одного и того же кода в REPL и загружая из файла можно получить неожиданные результаты.

В приведенном коде можно отметить, что *this* внутри функции *test* указывается на глобальный объект (window в браузере, global в node).

При выполнении кода в браузере или REPL переменная num добавлялась в глобальный объект, и ее значение можно было получить через `this`

При загрузке же из файла, переменная добавляется в модуль, а не в глобальный объект поэтому ее значение нельзя было получить через `this`.

Comment: Так вроде как это нормальное поведение. При объявлении var ты объявляешь в текущем контексте, а если без var то переменная будет  создана глобально, именно поэтому рекомендуют не объявлять пемеренные таким образом, и вроде как use strict явно запрещает это делать

Comment: @vnn198, простой пример, загрузив файл со строкой `var num=11`  в браузер - в window добавится поле, в node - нет. В этом и была проблема автора вопроса.

Comment: ну да, если во втором примере убрать var из первой строчки то всё работает, хотя по хорошему для ноды так объявлять переменные нельзя.